# django ORM returning an SQL syntax exception when using paginator

Tags: django, django-orm

this is a very weird problem, I've been working on a complex query that uses extra which works perfectly. When am using the queryset normally, it works and i can list the objects in the template all is okay.

but, when I apply paginator, it gives me an error. After couple hours of debugging, I tried to put a print statement for my query and suprisingly it worked. Below is my code

```
 queryset=get_model('vehicle', 'car').objects.my_cars(language=request.LANGUAGE_CODE, user=request.user)
    paginator = Paginator(
        queryset,
        10
    )

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        print getattr(queryset, 'query')
        cars = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        cars = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        cars = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response(
        'accounts/profile/my_vehicle.html',
            {
                'my_cars' : cars.object_list,
            },
        RequestContext(request)
    )
```

the moment i remove the statement print queryset.query it gives a mysql syntax error. If i keep it, it goes through. Any one experienced anything like that before?

Edited:

Error am getting is following

```
DatabaseError at /en/account/profile/my-vehicles/

(1054, "Unknown column 'vehicle_modellookup.id' in 'where clause'")
```

Comment: *"but, when I apply paginator, it gives me an error"* - how about post this error? :)

Comment: sure init3, i just edited my post with the error am getting

Comment: What about 'django-admin.py test'? Do model tests pass successfully?

Comment: I didn't do the test. Honestly, I don't know how.. Although i tried just now to run ./manage.py test and it went on without errors. I don't know if am suppose to write up any manual test cases or this is enough

Comment: I don't think I can help you much, but here's what I think: the print statement causes the queryset to be evaluated (which works fine). Then the paginator uses the cached results from the queryset to get the items. When the print is missing I believe the paginator attempts to modify the queryset to obtain only the needed items from the database. I suspect this brakes your work with the custom manager.